# How to tell periodicity of polar curve?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

For example, we want to find arc length of $r=\cos(\theta)$. Students often integrate from $0$ to $2\pi$ which is wrong since the curve starts to repeat it self after $\pi$. Drawing such curve will be one way. But I can imagine much more complicated curve that is hard to draw. Is there anyway to quickly tell what the periodicity is for a polar curve.

Comment: To find an arc length you need to define an arc. $r=cos(\theta)$ does not define an arc unless you specify limits for $\theta$.

Comment: @nicoguaro I think it's quite clear this is hidden and we want the length of the entire enclosed curve defined by the equation. It's like in catesian coordinate, I give you an equation $x^+y^2=1$ and want you to find length of the enclosed curve.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thank you. But can you illustrate with the example given? Otherwise, I don't know what you are saying.

Comment: I don't think it is that clear. For example, the arc length might represent the work done on certain system and you can go over $2\pi$. Or, in a more germane example, you have a thread that goes for two or three turns ...

Comment: Indeed it seems different treatments can define "curve" differently, even different treatments using parametric equations to do so. So it would be good to be very clear about which definition is being used when asking a question like this. (Perhaps also in class as well as on MSE.) https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Line_(curve)

Comment: @nicoguaro Do you understand the problem now? It is just asking the distance you travel on the curve once.

Comment: ... equating two points when they are at the same location in the plane, not just when they are images of the same value of the parameter; that is the intended interpretation, is it not?

Comment: well one way a curve can repeat is if f(x+2π)=f(x) or if f(x+π)=-f(x). i dont see any ways that a curve can repeat otherwise

Comment: I understand it, but I don't think that "students" are wrong ... maybe they're faced with an ambiguous statement.

Comment: How about a curve like $r = f(x) = \cos(\tan x)$ defined on $x \in [-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2].$ The function $f$ is not periodic in $x.$ Now what if we disguise the formula of $f$ so it's not so obviously a cosine of something. I could see playing games like this to defeat any simple decision algorithm, provided you are told the algorithm before you have to give the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the comments are very focused on the technical definition of arc length and of functions, which I think is above the grasp of the student level we are working with here. We simply want to get a geometric intuition. When does the curve start to repeat itself? After that, we don't count any more arc length.

One way to help figure out when a curve begins to repeat would be to ask students to find when $r$ comes back to its initial value. However, the nuance is that in polar coordinates $r$ can be negative, so one will have to find when $|r|$ returns to its initial value. Any time a curve repeats this is a necessary condition. It is not a sufficient condition, but checking for the periodicity of $|r|$ should narrow down the set of periodicities one could check to only a few. Then you can simply find the smallest one, and integrate over that period.